# How to setup wxWidgets in VSCode for GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, wxwidgets

I'm trying to make a GUI-Project with wxWidgets. Instead of using Visual Studio I want to use VSCode with the GCC (MinGW).
I'm facing the following problem: **I can't compile or run any code which has wxWidgets librarys included. How have the c_cpp_properties.json and the tasks.json files to be configured?**

I already went through the instructions for installing wxWidgets using "Cygwin/MinGW Compilation" part "Using plain makefiles:". (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.2/plat_msw_install.html)
1. cd .../wxWidgets-3.1.2\build\msw
2. mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc (for generating Build=debug per default)

And added following to my files:
*tasks.json:*

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "cApp.cpp", 
                "-I", "D:/Programme/wxWidgets-3.1.2/include/msvc", 
                "-I", "D:/Programme/wxWidgets-3.1.2/include", 
                "-L", "${WXWIN}/lib/vc_lib"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*c_cpp_properties.json:*

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${WXWIN}/include/msvc",
                "${WXWIN}/include"
            ],
            "browse": { "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "path": [
                    "${WXWIN}/include/msvc",
                    "${WXWIN}/include"
                ]
            },
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "__WXMSW__",
                "NDEBUG",
                "WXUSINGDLL"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "E:/Programme/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I", "${WXWIN}/include/msvc",
                "-I", "${WXWIN}/include",
                "-L", "${WXWIN}/gcc_lib",
                "-L", "${WXWIN}/gcc_lib/mswud"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I got the following error from my own code while compiling, which uses `#include "wx/wx.h"`:

```
                 from ${WXWIN}/include/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from ${WXWIN}/include/wx/wx.h:14,
                 from ${Project}\VSC-Basic-ProjectSetup\src\cMain.h:1,
                 from ${Project}\VSC-Basic-ProjectSetup\src\cMain.cpp:1:
${WXWIN}/include/msvc/wx/setup.h:12:6: error: #error "This file should only be included when 
     #error "This file should only be included when using Microsoft Visual C++"
      ^~~~~
...
...
...
In file included from ${WXWIN}/include/wx/platform.h:148:0,
                 from ${WXWIN}/include/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from ${WXWIN}/include/wx/wx.h:14,
                 from ${Project}\VSC-Basic-ProjectSetup\src\cMain.h:1,
                 from ${Project}\VSC-Basic-ProjectSetup\src\cMain.cpp:1:
${WXWIN}/include/msvc/wx/setup.h:125:27: fatal error: ../../../lib/vc_lib /msw /wx/setup.h: N
 #include wxSETUPH_PATH_STR
                           ^
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

${WXWIN}, ${Project} are just placeholders.

Comment: First of all you command should be: `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug` in order to create debug build. Second, the error you receive is from compiling the library itself or your own code? Third, why do you need vscode? All you do now is use the build you have and compile your own code. Can you clarify?

Comment: First, thanks for the tipp and I got the error from compiling my own code (edit). I'd like to develop my entire project in vscode, though I could compile it simply with the shell.

Comment: I can't answer your question as I've never used VS code, but you definitely must **not** use anything with `msvc` or `vc` in its name (like `D:/Programme/wxWidgets-3.1.2/include/msvc` or `${WXWIN}/lib/vc_lib`) when using gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's little bit too late but here is "Hello World" project for VSCode. You can observe all required includes and libraries to successfully compile & link your project in VSCode. All 3 major OS's are included in project.
https://github.com/huckor/wxwidgets-vscode